# Laravel 5 Custom ServiceProvider not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, package, teamleader

I'm making a Laravel ServiceProvider for a package.
The package is https://github.com/sumocoders/Teamleader

I get the following error

> FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 150:
>   Class 'Notflip\Teamleader\TeamleaderServiceProvider' not found

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong, Here's my folder structure

[image]

**composer.json in my package**

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
       "Notflip\\Teamleader": "src/"
    }
}
```

**TeamleaderServiceProvider**

```
<?php namespace Teamleader\Laravel;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class TeamleaderServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register bindings in the container.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function publishes()
    {
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__.'/Config/config.php' => config_path('teamleader.php'),
        ]);
    }
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('Teamleader\Laravel', function () {
            return new Teamleader(config('teamleader.API_GROUP'), config('teamleader.API_SECRET'), config('teamleader.SSL'));
        });
    }
}
```

**Facade**

```
<?php namespace Teamleader\Laravel\Facade;

class Teamleader extends Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'Teamleader';
    }
}
```

In my **config.php** I added the following line to the providers

```
'Notflip\Teamleader\TeamleaderServiceProvider',
```

And this line to the aliasses

```
'Teamleader'=> 'Notflip\Teamleader\Facade\Teamleader'
```

Anyone has any idea what I might be doing wrong? Thank you! I'm so close to the result!

Comment: Have you set up a custom namespace for `\Notflip\Teamleader` pointing to your src folder?

Comment: yes! i added it to the question

Comment: have you namespaced your `TeamleaderServiceProvider` service provider?

Comment: yes! sorry, edited question again, indentation was off.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition in composer is missing the initial slashes and you haven't specified the path to src from root.

```
"psr-4": {
   "\\Notflip\\Teamleader": "notflip/teamleader-laravel/src/"
}
```

Also your declaration of the name space at the top of TeamleaderServiceProvider is wrong, it should be:

```
<?php namespace Notflip\Teamleader;
```

Comment: It's still giving the same error, thanks for your answer!

Comment: Oh and i'm wondering, all the other packages in the vendor/ folder don't specify the namespace from the root? They're all doing what I'm doing. just Vendor/Package: src

Comment: Hhm, i don't see any signs of teamleader in the vendor/composer/autoload-psr4.

Answer (score 0):

## Solved

In the facade, the IOC binding was named wrong ( wrong case )

> The name should have been 'teamleader' in lowercase.

**Facade**

```
class Teamleader extends Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'teamleader';
    }
}
```

**Service Provider**

```
<?php namespace Teamleader\Laravel;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class TeamleaderServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register bindings in the container.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function publishes()
    {
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__.'/Config/config.php' => config_path('teamleader.php'),
        ]);
    }
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('teamleader', function () {
            return new Teamleader(config('teamleader.API_GROUP'), config('teamleader.API_SECRET'), config('teamleader.SSL'));
        });
    }
}
```